# how can i convert query syntax to fluent syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I wanna convert query syntax to fluent syntax but I can't do it. I don't know can I use two clauses "where" in fluent syntax in this code?

```
public static void Ex6()
{
    string[] csvRecipes = { "milk,sugar,eggs", "flour,BUTTER,eggs", "vanilla,ChEEsE,oats" };
    var dairQuery=
        from csvRecipe in csvRecipes
        let ingredients = csvRecipe.Split(',')
        from ingredient in ingredients
        let uppercaseIngredient=ingredient.ToUpper()
        where uppercaseIngredient =="MILK" ||
        uppercaseIngredient == "BUTTER" ||
        uppercaseIngredient == "CHEESE"
        select uppercaseIngredient;
    foreach (var item in dairQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is dairy", item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `join`s are especially cleaner in query syntax.  If you're just doing it as a learning exercise that's fine, but don't be pedantic about using one or the other.

Comment: Use Linqpad for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does pretty much, what you want.

```
var query = csvRecipes.Select(x => x.Split(','))
                       //flatten the list
                       .SelectMany(y => y)
                       //ToUppercase Again
                       .Select(x => x.ToUpper())
                       .Where(i => i == "MILK" ||
                                   i == "BUTTER" ||
                                   i == "CHEESE");
```

If you want to compare strings ignoring the ordinal case, you can use `i => i.Equals("MILK", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 0):

> can I use two clauses "where" in fluent syntax in this code?

You can chain `Where` clauses, but then they are interpreted as `AND` clauses instead of `OR` clauses (since the data must pass through all `Where` filters).

The appropriate way to convert that where clause to fluent would be:

```
.Where(item => item.uppercaseIngredient == "MILK" ||
               item.uppercaseIngredient == "BUTTER" ||
               item.uppercaseIngredient == "CHEESE")
```

Alternatively you could use a collection of items and `Contains`:

```
var validTypes = new string[] { "MILK", "BUTTER", "CHEESE"};

...
.Where(item => validTypes.Contains(item.uppercaseIngredient))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a collection where you store the ingredients you want to select. Then you can use `SelectMany` to find all matching tokens with this concise query:

```
string[] ingredients = new[] { "MILK", "BUTTER", "CHEESE" };
var dairQuery = csvRecipes
    .SelectMany(r => r.Split(',').Select(i => i.ToUpper()).Where(ingredients.Contains));
```